# Modal Logic: Point-wise equivalence vs. (simple) equivalence

Tags: modal-logic

I am reading Brain Chellas' *Modal Logic* and have a question regarding point-wise and (simple) equivalence: what is a scenario in which two models are equivalent but not point-wise equivalent?

Say, for example, that we have two models such that:

`M1 = <W: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, P: {{1}, {2, 3}, {5}}>`

`M2 = <W: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, P: {{2}, {3, 4}, {5}}>`

`M1` assigns *p* to {1}, *q* to {2, 3}, and *r* to {5} and `M2` assigns *p* to {2}, *q* to {3, 4}, and *r* to {5}. Are the models point-wise equivalent? Are they (simply) equivalent? Why?

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointwise equivalence of two models *M* and *N* means that there is a bijection between the sets of worlds such that two corresponding worlds make the same sentences true, whereas equivalence between *M* and *N* means that the sets of valid sentences on the whole models are equal to each other.

Your example is pointwise equivalent, by mapping *M1* to *M2* as 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 5.

For an easy example of equivalent models that are not pointwise equivalent, let *N* be some finite model, and *M* be the disjoint union of two copies of *N*. There does not exist a bijection between these models, since their sets of worlds have different cardinality. However, both models make the same sentences true.

For another example, consider a reflexive model *M* consisting of a single world, and the model *N* with two worlds that reach each other (but not themselves) and both have the same valuation as the world of *M*.

---

Note that two pointwise equivalent models *M* and *N* are also equivalent, since if a sentence holds on the whole model *M*, it holds in every world of *M*, and thus by pointwise equivalence it holds in every world of *N*, and therefore on the whole model *N*.

Comment: Great Answer, clear and to the point! Welcome to Philosophy SE!